# xkeyval Error: 'autolang'

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to use Kile for the first time, and I am getting all kinds of errors. I have worked through some of them, but I can't solve this one: I am getting an "xkeyval Error: 'autolang' undefined in families" and so on. As far as I can tell, it says that it is undefined for biblatex, but it certainly should be. What should I do?

Here is an example of what causes the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

and it gives me the error

```
[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:10299:Package keyval Error: autolang undefined \blx@processoptions
./Thing:0:'babel' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
./Thing:0:No file Thing.aux.
./Thing:0:No file Thing.bbl.
```

I named the file Thing.tex, fyi.

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added an example - I hope that is what you meant :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's already helping a lot. It should be `\documentclass{article}` (curly brackets), however. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error message you're getting -- I had no trouble compiling it with that change made...

Comment: Could you try adding the command `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in the second line. i.e.  _before_ the biblatex-command?

Comment: Works for me too (after correcting the `[article]` error)

Comment: I corrected the mistake and added your corrections and the entire log. It works fine in TexShop on my mac, but for some reason it doesn't work in Kile on linux

Comment: I get the error if I compile with TeX Live 2012. This seems to imply that the TeX system on your Linux box is very old and outdated.

Comment: I do the "sudo apt-get update" every day, does that not update it? Do you know how to update it then?

Comment: What's the output of `pdftex --version` (from a terminal window) on the Linux box and on the Mac? You probably have a very old Linux system, so updates are frozen.

Comment: The option `autolang` used to be called `babel`, it was renamed in version 2.8 from 2013-10-21. So if your `biblatex` version is 2.7 or below (so dates back more than four years now) you must use `babel=hyphen`.

Comment: On my Mac it says it is TexLive 2015, and on the Linux box it says TexLive 2016 for pdftex --version. But replacing autolang with babel did the trick :) I would still prefer to have everything up to date, but I don't know how

Comment: Do you have the problem on both your Mac and Linux machine? Do you have multiple versions of TeX live installed? How many files do you find if you search for `biblatex.sty` on your computer, where are those files located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error using the `autloang` option you must be using a very old version of `biblatex`. The option used to be called `babel` and was renamed in version 2.8 (released 2013-10-21). The old code is

```
babel=hyphen
```